# GAS Assembler operand type mismatch for `cmovz'

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I am trying to write a simple assembly program.  For some reason the conditional moves seem to give me this error.  If I replace them with normal mov instruction it works.  What is wrong with the following code?

```
    .section .data

supported:
    .asciz "AVX is supported"
notsupported:
    .asciz "AVX is not supported"


    .section .text
    .global main
main:
    movq $1, %rax
    cpuid
    andq $0x10000000, %rcx
    cmovnz $supported, %rdi
    cmovz $notsupported, %rdi
    callq puts

    movq $0, %rax
    ret
cpuid.S:15: Error: operand type mismatch for `cmovnz'
cpuid.S:16: Error: operand type mismatch for `cmovz'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the description of `CMOVcc` in Intel's manual you'll see that the source operand needs to be an `r/m64` (i.e. a 64-bit register or memory location). `$supported` and `$notsupported` are immediates, and therefore do not qualify as an `r/m64`.

You could do something like this:

```
movabs $notsupported,%rdi
movabs $supported,%rbx
testq $0x10000000, %rcx   # checks the desired bit without clobbering %rcx
cmovnz %rbx,%rdi
```

Comment: Can you also do me a favor and explain what movabs does which is different than say movq?

Comment: When using `movq $supported,%rbx`, you'd get machine code where the immediate is encoded in 32 bits, which is likely to result in relocation errors during linking. Hence the reason for using `movabs`, which results in the immediate being encoded in 64 bits.

Comment: That is, when assembling, the addresses of your labels are not yet known. So the assembler just outputs offsets relative to the start of the section in which they are located. Those offsets may well be small enough to fit in 32 bits, but when the linker steps in and assigns addresses to the sections and relocate the code accordingly, those addresses may well require 64 bits.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `leaq something(%rip), %rdi`?

Comment: @harold: That does indeed result in 2 bytes less machine code for each addresses loaded.

Comment: If the condition for cmov is usually false, it would save an instruction to put the constant in memory, instead of as an immediate.  Then `cmov my_const(%rip), %rdi`.  If it happens often, that's an extra cache line (and even memory page) that can miss in the L1 D-cache and DTLB.